# This text is {\usebeamercolor*{example text} example} not working

Tags: beamer, color

This command should display the word 'example' in green, but it prints in the normal text colour, i.e. black.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Using the default `beamer` settings, `{\usebeamercolor[fg]{example text} example}` would print green text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted,
\usebeamercolor*{example text}example} resets all the colours and prints the "example" in normal text.
To get green colored text,
\usebeamercolor[fg]{example text} example} works.
But according to the manual, \usebeamercolor{example text} example}, should also work. But unfortunately, I don't see that working in my document.